# Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Tags: java, apache, websocket

I trying a simple websocket application but its giving a error,

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/WebSocketPrj02/chatroomServerEndpoint' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404
```

I found to many discussions on the same topic but it didn't help me that's why I posting a new question.

My files are,
**ChatroomServerEndpoint.java**

```
package com.za.tutorial.websocket;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.json.JsonWriter;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;


@ServerEndpoint("chatroomServerEndpoint")
public class ChatroomServerEndpoint {

    static Set<Session> chatroomUsers = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());

    @OnOpen
    public void handleOpen(Session userSession){
        chatroomUsers.add(userSession);
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void handleMessage(String message, Session userSession) throws IOException{
        String userName = (String) userSession.getUserProperties().get("userNmae");
        if(userName == null){
            userSession.getUserProperties().put("userName", userName);
            userSession.getBasicRemote().sendText(buildJsonData("System"," you are connected as "+message));
        } else {
            Iterator<Session> iterator = chatroomUsers.iterator();
            while(iterator.hasNext()){
                iterator.next().getBasicRemote().sendText(buildJsonData(userName, message));
            }
        }
    }

    private String buildJsonData(String userName, String message) {
        JsonObject jsonObject = Json.createObjectBuilder().add("message", userName+": "+message).build();
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        try(JsonWriter jsonWriter = Json.createWriter(stringWriter)){
            jsonWriter.write(jsonObject);
        }
        return stringWriter.toString();
    }
}
```

**default.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Websocket2</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var websocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/WebSocketPrj02/chatroomServerEndpoint")
            websocket.onmessage = function processMessage(message) {
                var jsonData = JSON.parse(message.data);
                if(jsonData.message != null){
                    messagesTextArea.value += jsonData.message +"\n";
                }
            }

            function sendMessage() {
                websocket.send(messageText.value);
                messageText.value = "";
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <textarea id="messagesTextArea" readonly="readonly" rows="10" cols="45"></textarea><br>
        <input type = "text" id="messageText" size="50">
        <input type="button" value="send" onclick="sendMessage();">
    </body>
</html>
```

I am using Spring Tool Suit, apache-tomcat-7.0.37.
I went through all suggestion given in the related stack overflow post, but still its not working.
I know its very simple but still giving error. I am totally stuck here. Can please any one help me for this??

Comment: 404 means "Not Found", that would suggest me that I had to map the WebSocketServlet on the web.xml file... But I am not sure how it would work with your framework... By the way, I'm assuming you're deploying on your own host and not on a server, right?

Comment: I am running it on localhost

Answer (score 0):

Finally problem is solved. I just switched from Eclipse to Netbeans and from Apache tomcat to Glassfish, now its working fine for me.